# Skip Beat in a Measure

Tags: piano, notation

Can we skip some/a beat(s) in a measure in music notation?

In the picure, I want to skip that quarter rest so we can play directly the next c note?

[image]

Comment: Is this a piece you have written, or a piece you're playing that someone else wrote?

Comment: It's a piece I'm writing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To "skip" a beat, change the time signature for that measure. In the specific case in the question, the time signature for the measure shown would be 3/4, then the following measure would return to the original time signature. Here's an example of some music in 4/4 time, switching the 3/4 (i.e., "skipping a beat"), then returning to 4/4 time.

[image: Change from 4/4 to 3/4 and back]

Comment: Wow it works! Tnkiu!

Comment: That's an interesting interpretation of that melody :-)

Comment: Stravinsky's "Twelve Variations on *Ah! vous dirai-je, Maman*"?

Comment: @Wastrel I don't know what you're talking about. This is a totally original composition. :-)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Now I'm hearing "Twinkle" with the *Rite of String* chords under each note.